# Column-Oriented Databases for Financial Data Analysis

Tags: database, postgresql, nosql, finance

I currently have a lot of financial data I would like to analyze and compute on. I have built a data system that reads from flat-files and does some decently intelligent caching to maintain the performance I want. But I am starting to have to much data for this system...

I was currently thinking about using POSTGres and having a schema sort of like this:

```
Table: Things
Fields: T_id, Row, Sub-Row, Column, Resolution, Readable-Name, Meta

Table: Data
Fields: d_id, T_id, timestamp, value
```

I was wondering if POSTGres would be performant with the above schema if my data table has billions of rows.

Another Idea I had was using a column-oriented database, but I can't seem to find any good open-source ones to get started with. Cassandra is really not made for this situation as I will be reading much much more than writing.

Comment: It sounds like you have an OLAP workload (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). If so, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema .

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your expecting - PostgreSQL probably can process this queries on your schema, but it can be a minutes or hours long query - depends on processed rows - but column store databases can be faster about 10 times - just PostgreSQL is relational OLTP database and your schema is not well normalized and probably you prefer OLAP.

There are some open source column store databases like MonetDB or LucidDB, but they are not from PostgreSQL's space. There are only commercial database Vertica. You can look on MySQL engines http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/08/16/testing-mysql-column-stores/

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on your budget.

Here is list of solutions which we using on practice(from cheap to expensive):

MongoDB
PostgreSQL
InfiniDB
kdb+